# Unable to reference native Android view in Xamarin xaml

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using baseflow's MediaManager plugin:

https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager

I need to have multiple video views. From reading the documentation, I know I need to create a video view using native android views in my xaml like this:

```
<mediamanager.platforms.android.video.VideoView
    android:id="@+id/your_videoview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp" />
```

I used the following documentation to try and add native view support:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/xaml

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to correctly reference 'android:'. I've added the references and I've set [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Skip)] but still I get the squiggly green lines. I've also cleaned/rebuilt/deleted bin/obj files.

[image]

[image]

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, maybe there is a code wizard out there that can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need to use any of that! You should try the brand new ‘MediaElement’ control on Xamarin forms. It makes adding videos a piece of cake:

```
<MediaElement Source="https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/5d93/a1eab4bf-3288-4faf-81c4-294402a85d93/XamarinShow_mid.mp4"
          ShowsPlaybackControls="True" />
```

Even though it’s in preview, it works really smoothly, I watched it in a Kym Philpotts live demo during MS Build 2020. Check out the official docs for it over here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/mediaelement

Here’s a video to the recorded stream too: https://youtube.com/watch?v=dMR6uaFz0Eg

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion! When I'm back in office Monday I will take a look at this and give it a go.

Comment: Yes, but he needs to have multiple video views, as he stated in th question. So this approach won't work.

Comment: Hey @Mihail-Duchev why not? Can’t you just create multiple MediaElement controls like you can do multiple labels?

Comment: Yes thank you, I'm using media element now. It's been easy to implement but I am getting one problem. I can't get the player to release the source, despite setting it's source to null and calling Stop(). The video remains loaded in the player.

Comment: MediaElement is immensely buggy.

Comment: They are making fixes for it too, and are accepting PR's. Please file it as an issue https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+mediaelement

Answer (score 0):

You **can** use native views in Forms. Unfortunately, this here is not the case. Your native view needs its own `*.axml` file in the Android project in order for you to use it.

Looking at the rest of the code that you need for this particular configuration, it should also be written natively (in the Android project) - `FindViewById` && `SetView` are all code that needs to be in the Android project.

Unfortunately, in some cases not everything has been prepared for usage in the shared project and occasionally you need to get "your hands dirty" and go "native" in order to configure your code the way you wish.

What you should do it use it as it is being shown in [Xamarin.Forms section](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager#xamarinforms). Then, you can apply the modifications that are documented in [Add Video Player to the UI](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager#add-video-player-to-the-ui). You can create a class that inherits from [VideoViewRenderer](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager/blob/develop/MediaManager.Forms/Platforms/Android/VideoViewRenderer.cs) and modify your view there. If you are not familiar with customs renderers, you can read more about them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/).

Comment: This is not correct, you CAN reference native controls in XAML: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/xaml

Comment: Yes, my bad. I have corrected my answer. Even though we can use the native views, the configuration requires that it is being done natively.

Comment: Thanks guys. @MihailDuchev I'm a little confused. I've only tinkered with the layout through the xaml files. If I need to use an axml file, does that mean I need to completely re-do the layout and discard my xaml files?

Comment: No. What will happen is this - you will have code in 2 places - shared & android projects. In the shared project, you will use the `<mm:VideoView` and in the native project you will simply modify it a bit - replacing your view with your **axml** `mediamanager.platforms.android.video.VideoView`. What this means is that you will use the code in Forms, but you will simple "extend" the view's functionality. Read more about how custom renderers work and you will get the flow. :)

Comment: No, you do not need to use `AXML` to wrap the view.

Comment: According to the documentation, you do: `If you have multiple video views and you want to hook it up yourself do...After that you can manually add the video view like this:` Ref: https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager#add-video-player-to-the-ui